# Цикл по результату os.system ведёт к ошибке TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
import os 

ip = os.system('netstat')
file = open('ip.txt', 'w')

for i in ip:
    file.write(ip)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

> **os.system(command)** - исполняет системную команду, возвращает код её
>   завершения (в случае успеха 0)

В `ip` будет хранится код (число) завершения программы, то есть `int`, а не список открытых соединений.

Если совсем топорно, то можно так

```
os.system('netstat > ip.txt')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: на [github](https://github.com/da667/netstat/blob/master/netstat.py) есть реализация, но только для Linux